# Adding TabBar item icons by code, not interface builder?

Tags: ios, icons, tabbar

I'm making an app with the Dapp app, but I can't manage to add the tab bar icons correctly. So, is there a way to add the icons to the tab bar coding it? Like something on the AppDelegate, without using Interface Builder. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`UITabBarController` derives all of the information necessary to create a tab bar item for each view controller by inspecting the view controller itself.

All you need to do is assign an array of view controllers using `-setViewControllers:animated:`.

Once a view controller is added to a tab bar controller, the tab bar controller will inspect the view controller's `tabBarItem` property. This tab bar item will be inserted into the tab bar controller's tab bar automatically.
You can initialize a tab bar in each view controller programmatically. It looks something like this...

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"] tag:1];
```

or if you want to use one of the system items...

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFeatured tag:1];
```

I suggest you take a look at the [`UITabBarController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [`UITabBarItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class references and read up on the relevant properties. The docs are filled with indispensable information.

Comment: I like this solution, but I can't seem to set the tab bar item's custom title once it's got a system item attached to it. *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, so if you have your 30x30 .png files in your resources, this should just be a matter of adding code like what follows. You would put this in your init method of the view controller associated with the tab bar index.

```
//get the tab bar item
            UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];

            //Give it a label
            [tbi setTitle:@"Item One"];

            //create a UIImage from a file
            UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyItem.png"];

            //put that image on the tab bar item
            [tbi setImage:i];
```